# install Derivatives of hachoir library into Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, hachoir-parser

How can I install derivatives of hachoir library like `hachoir-core` Or `hachoir-metadata` on GoogleColab? I tried this way `!pip install hachoir-metadata` but I got the error

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-install-8op487i8/hachoir-metadata/

Answer (score 0):

`!pip2 install hachoir-metadata` works fine for me, and https://pypi.org/project/hachoir-metadata/ says "Last released in 2010" suggesting the package is incompatible with Python 3. Try changing your notebook setting to Python 2.

Comment: I can't do that ! it should be an another way to compatible with python 3 setting

Comment: `!pip3 install --no-clean hachoir-metadata` will leave the installation directory behind, and if you look in the `setup.py` file in there you'll see it is using python 2 syntax (e.g. `print >> sys.stderr`) that is invalid in python 3.
If python 2 is not an option for you then I suggest you find a more modern library to accomplish your goals than `hachoir-metadata`.

Comment: On the other hand, it looks like `!pip install hachoir3` does work and has a `hachoir.metadata` submodule; maybe that's what you want?
(if it isn't, stating explicitly what you're trying to accomplish might be a faster path to getting useful advice)